# How can you embed PHP within a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, validation, cakephp, captcha

I am trying to add a CAPTCHA option to a specific page on a website. The validation code for the page is written in Javascript, and the PHP CAPTCHA documentation (http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart-guide/) is given strictly in PHP. I've managed to add the CAPTCHA box to the page and everything else up until where the code verifies the user's CAPTCHA entry. I am having trouble merging the two because:

a) they are written in different languages
b) my knowledge in PHP/Javascript is very basic

Here is a snippet of the page's original validation code:

```
function validate(formData, jqForm, options){

    // # Valid?
    valid = false;

    // # Validate Contact Form
    var errs = new Array();

    // # Contact Name
    if($('#ContactName').val() == ''){
        errs.push(['#ContactName', 'Enter your name.']);
    } else if(label = $('#ContactNameLabel label.error-message')){
        label.fadeOut();
    }
```

I want to repeat the same process except with the user's CAPTCHA entry. The following code is given in the PHP CAPTCHA documentation:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php';

$securimage = new Securimage();
```

and

```
if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
    // the code was incorrect
    // you should handle the error so that the form processor doesn't continue

    // or you can use the following code if there is no validation or you do not know how
    echo "The security code entered was incorrect.<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.";
    exit;
}
```

The code can be found, along with instructions, in the link given above. My question is: how can I implement the given PHP code inside the Javascript function that I have? To my understanding, it is possible to embed PHP inside Javascript as long as the forum is written using PHP (and I can confirm that the website I'm working on is built using CakePHP) - I am just lost with the syntax/how to go about executing this (if it is possible).

If anyone could offer me a helping hand that would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between **server-side** code and **client-side** code.

Comment: And after understanding that, you simply need to post that form to a PHP code that will check captcha code. You don't ve to embed it in JS

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. @Hanky웃Panky could you give me a bit more of an insight to what you're referring to? I'm assuming (please correct me if I'm wrong), create a variable inside the JS that is passed to the PHP form as a POST parameter, and once that is validated it is passed back to the JS, and the page continues as usual. Is this what you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You can write PHP within JavaScript if the JavaScript is in the View (as opposed to being in a `.js` file)

**Example:**

```
<?php
$message = "Hello World";
?>

<script>
    alert("<?php echo $message; ?>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as PHP is a server-side language and Javascript is a client-side one.  By the time your browser sees the page, all the PHP processing has finished on the server and all that's left is client-side rendering of the page.  You will need to validate the CAPTCHA on the server-side.

Comment: Yes.  Also, if you validate with javascript and not on the server side, there is nothing stopping someone from bypassing the javascript validation and spamming your form anyways.  This defeats the purpose of the captcha

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. @Nightwolf how do you suggest I go about doing this? The PHP CAPTCHA website suggests that you do the CAPTCHA validation after you've processed all of the other entries (such as name, email etc..) Thus I'm confused as to how I can incorporate it without touching the existing javascript. Do you think that this isn't possible/it should be redone from scratch?